# Downloading file from database where file is stored in binary format

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, download, binary

I have got stuck in a problem while downloading documents from database.

Currently I'm working in ASP.net project and this is my first career project.
We have some documents which we store in database. The documents(.pdf,.doc,.png,.docx,xls,xlsx) are stored in binary format with their type specified.

I can download one document using Response.write. But now i have to concatenate some documents and then allow user to download on button click.

I have googled a lot. Developers have said that this is impossible. But still i feel that this can be done.

However if this is impossible i thought that i will save these individual documents first at some server location and then zip them and then allow user to download. But how would i be able to save the individual document in their original format at server location.

Please help me out. I'm in big problem.

Comment: Zipping the files seems to be the way to go. You could retrieve the documents from your database, convert them to the type of the document (which you have specified in your database) and add them to a ZIP file. Depending on the size of the files, you can do this in memory and offer the ZIP file to a user. Otherwise, you could write the documents to disk (on your server) and then create a ZIP file. After you created the ZIP file, you can delete the documents and after downloading, delete the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not impossible to read more than one document from a database and zip them up before presenting the zip file to the response stream. You can do this all in process, there is no need to save the documents to the server.

This code uses `Ionic.Zip` to zip up several files and write them to a `MemoryStream`:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    zipFile.AddEntry(file.FileName, file.ContentBytes);  // these are the file bytes
}
var zipMs = new MemoryStream();
zipFile.Save(zipMs);
zipMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
zipMs.Flush();
```

The `file.FileName` includes the extensions (.docx) of the documents and when downloading through the browser, everything is displayed and saved correctly.

Comment: Thank u so much.....Stefan and Davin....i'll try it in half an hour and then tell you the result